# How to make remap Alt to Win button when there are Xbox Game key-bindings

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, autohotkey, key-binding

I would like to bind my `LAlt` to `LWin` button. I have the AutoHotKey script:

```
LWin::LAlt
```

It works great except for a few key sentences: `Win-r`, `Win-g`, `Win-b`. They have their roots in Xbox Game application in Windows 10, but after I turned them off nothing changed and they still don't work. I have lost `Win-r`, `Win-g`, `Win-b`.
Could you advise me how I can fix it?

UPDATE.

Fix my post.

Comment: You are mapping your left-win key to left-alt, which is the opposite of what you describe. Please fix your post.

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) ```The syntax for the built-in remapping feature is``` **OriginKey::DestinationKey**. ```For example, a script consisting only of the following line would make the A key behave like the B key:```
**a::b**